# differences when using inline mode and \overline and \sqrt

Tags: inline, sqrt

Can anyone help me make this square root signs in the code below, be of the same size so that they all have the same height? This is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{book}


\begin{document}

$\overline{\sqrt{v_{x}^{2}}}$ and 
$\overline{\sqrt{v_{y}^{2}}}$ and 
$\overline{\sqrt{v_{h}^{2}}}$


\end{document}
```

Thanks

EDIT (13/08/2018):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig} %for subfigures


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[SUB CAPTION TEXT]{{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{image1.pdf} }}%
~
\subfloat[SUB CAPTION TEXT]{{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{image2.pdf} }}%
\newline
\subfloat[SUB CAPTION TEXT]{{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{image3.pdf} }}%
~
\subfloat[SUB CAPTION TEXT]{{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{image4.pdf} }}%
\caption{$\overline{\sqrt{v_{\vphantom{h}\smash{y}}^{2}}}$}%
\label{fig:du}%
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could put a use `{\strut x}` and same for y and h so all three have the same height and depth.

Comment: `\vphantom` and `\smash` are fragile; you need `\protect` in front of them when in a caption.

Comment: @egreg thanks, this was also pointed out by Bernard in another comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are solutions, based on `\smash` and `\vphantom`:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\begin{document}

$\overline{\sqrt{v_{x}^{2}}}$ and
$\overline{\sqrt{v_{\smash{y}}^{2}}}$ and
$\overline{\sqrt{v_{h}^{2}}}$\\

If you’re a perfectionist, you can also have the exponent 2 at the same height: \\

$\overline{\sqrt{v_{\vphantom{h}x}^{2}}}$ and
$\overline{\sqrt{v_{\vphantom{h}\smash{y}}^{2}}}$ and
$\overline{\sqrt{v_{h}^{2}}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any effect with \smash{y} in your answer. Both lines look identitical, to me.

Comment: @pzorba75: `\smash{y}` suppresses the effect of the descender in*y* (the part below the baseline. The difference between  bothlines comes from adding `\vphantom{h}`which makes the exponent $2$ be placed exactly at the same height in all roots of the second line, whereas in the first line, the first two exponents are slightly lower. Zooming at  > 200 %, you can see it distinctly (the distance with the horizontal line of the square root is 0.9 pt in one case, 0.5pt in the other).

Comment: I received an error message:
`Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1334.`

This occurred when trying to use the syntax below in a caption for a figure:
`$\overline{\sqrt{v_{\vphantom{h}x}^{2}}}$`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `\strut`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
$\overline{\sqrt{\strut v_{x}^{2}}}$ and 
$\overline{\sqrt{\strut v_{y}^{2}}}$ and 
$\overline{\sqrt{\strut v_{h}^{2}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the error message:
`Incompatible list can't be unboxed. ...surements.\relax }}{50}{figure.caption.35}`when trying to use that syntax inside a caption for a figure.

Comment: @slew123: Do you have the same error message if you move this code outside \caption?

Comment: I have no error, even in a `\caption` of a figure.

Comment: @Bernard I'm using the symbol inside figures which are created using `graphicx` and `subfig` packages. Error occurs. No error when used outside a caption.

Comment: @slew123: Could you post a minimal example code reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Bernard I added the minimal code in the original post. For some reason, if I remove biblatex  it won't compile at all (even without the `$\overline{\sqrt{v_{\vphantom{h}\smash{y}}^{2}}}$` part.).

Comment: @slew123: That's because `\vphantom` is a fragile command and it must be protected. If you use `$\overline{\sqrt{v_{\protect\vphantom{h}\smash{y}}^{2}}}$`, it compiles without error. For the `biblatex` problem, simply delete all auxiliary files first.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry for the long reply, thanks, this has solved the problem. I will try to read a bit about fragile commands when I have some spare time from work.